# keep object size and position unchanged in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am beginner of as3. I am trying to keep object size and position static while the stage  size changing. I want my objects size and position same in any condition of the stage. the stage can be full screen, can be resized by user, can be resized by device. i have added a ball on my screen and when i click the ball screen goes full screen. but in full screen mode my ball change its position and size. it gets bigger. how to keep the ball on the top left corner of the stage. 
see the following screenshots and my code.
[image: Full Screen]

[image: Normal Screen]

**AS3 Code**

```
    package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;  
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class mainajaira extends MovieClip {
        private var _ball=new ball();
        private var stagewidht:Number=stage.stageWidth;


        public function mainajaira() {
            // constructor code
            addChild(_ball);
            _ball.x=0;
            _ball.y=0;
trace(_ball.height + "." + "." + _ball.width);
trace("Stage Width:" + stagewidht);
trace("Ball x: " + _ball.x);
_ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullscreen)
        }
        private function fullscreen(e:MouseEvent):void{
            if(stage.displayState==StageDisplayState.NORMAL){
                stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN}
                else if (stage.displayState==StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN){
                stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL}
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the stage will scale content (so your object dimensions are the same) instead of "expanding" to have extra area. You can adjust this with [StageScaleMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html). Your description sounds like you want `NO_SCALE`.

Typically:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Comment: @ Andy Savage 
Thanks for your kind help. 
is it possible to set stage.scaleMode and stage.align for a single object? and rest of the object will scaled by the stage. is it possible?